# Why does this bootstrap 4 dropdown menu not hide sibling submenus

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Could someone point out where I'm going wrong with this simplified version of my bootstrap 4 menu? If you look at Submenu 2 it has some solitary items plus a couple with submenus themselves.  If you activate either Submenu 2-3 or Submenu 2-4 the submenus expand as expected.  However if while one of those is already expanded you activate the other it expands but doesn't hide the one that was already expanded which is what I expect should happen.

I've looked at the suggested related questions here without finding a solution.  I've experimented with different parent and sibling selectors but can't seem to figure it out.  Here's the code for the example:

FWIW the original source for this was:
https://bootstrapious.com/p/bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown
I'm aware the solution will be jQuery/JS code.  I believe all the code that needs to be critiqued is at the end of the snippet.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
       .nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link{
  color: black;
  background: #D3D3D3;
  height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: .75rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  border-right: .1rem solid white;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  height: 1.5rem;
  font-size: .75rem;
  padding: .25rem;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  content: "\f0da";
  float: right;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
    </style>
   <title>Menu Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav id="smMenu" class="navbar navbar-light bg-white py-3 shadow-sm sticky-top">
  <div class="container">
   <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" class="navbar-toggler">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand font-weight-bold d-md-none float-right">Menu Test</a>
    <div id="navbarContent" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Solitary 1</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Solitary 2</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="dropdownMenu_0_2" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Submenu 1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 1-1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 1-2</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 1-3</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="dropdownMenu_0_6" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Submenu 2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 2-1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 2-2</a>
               </li>
               <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a id="dropdownMenu_0_6_12" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">Submenu 2-3</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">&gt;Submenu 2-3-1</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">&gt; Submenu 2-3-2</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
              <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                  <a id="dropdownMenu_0_6_13" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle">Submenu 2-4</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">&gt;Submenu 2-4-1</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">&gt;Submenu 2-4-2</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">&gt;Submenu 2-4-3</a>
                     </li>
                     <li>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">&gt;Submenu 2-4-4</a>
                     </li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 2-5</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a id="dropdownMenu_0_8" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">Submenu 3</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu border-0 shadow">
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 3-1</a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a tabindex="-1" href="#" class="dropdown-item">Submenu 3-2</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Solitary 3</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Solitary 4</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
<div>
</nav>
<div id="mainContent" class='container'>
   <h4 class='text-center'>Menu Test</h4>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
      //add the menu system dropdown functionality
      $("ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle='dropdown']").on("click", function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
         $(this).siblings().toggleClass("show");
         if (!$(this).next().hasClass('show')) {
            $(this).parents('.dropdown-menu').first().find('.show').removeClass("show");
         }
         $(this).parents('li.nav-item.dropdown.show').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', ".show",function(e) {
               $('.dropdown-submenu .show').removeClass("show");
          });
       });
    }
);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: for that you need to use JS

Comment: I'm aware the functionality will come from JS.  The code that's not working quite right is at the end of the snippet.